# IRC channel for iPhone developers?

Tags: iphone, irc

I was wondering if there is a good IRC channel around somewhere that allows iPhone developers to get together and talk about code and etc.

Any channel already around that people are using?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's #iphonedev on irc.freenode.net. Without the dash.

There's also #cocoa-init. It's a new channel focused on asking and answering questions for beginning developers on iOS/OSX.

Comment: it's need a registration :\

Comment: To register see http://superuser.com/a/322897/143895

Answer (score 10):

the people on #iphonedev are not very friendly.

Comment: There are a few arrogant people in there, but that's what /ignore is for, eh? :)

Comment: Bad people are everywhere ! they are evil.Just ignore them.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the various iphone channels on irc.osx86.hu to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`#iphonedev` on `irc.freenode.net`

Comment: Thanks, I'm there now. It's just really empty in there (just some other lurker and I now). Is there another channel that is a bit busier?

Comment: it's `#iphonedev`, by the by.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the NDA that Apple forces iPhone developers to sign would prevent them from participating in such a discussion.

EDIT: See the comments to my answer. Apparently the NDA was lifted as of 10/01/08. So if the sort of resource you are looking for doesn't exist now, hopefully it will soon.

Comment: The NDA has been lifted on October 1st, so that's not a concern anymore.

Comment: Good to know. I'll leave my answer just so that your comment will be seen and credited to you but change my answer to community wiki.