# IRC channel for Java Mobile development?

Tags: java-me, mobile, midlet

I'm trying to get an idea of how difficult it would be to build a simple application for feature phones, and the best way I can come up with is to learn the Java for Mobile Devices framework and dive into writing something.

However, I'd like to be able to chat with other developers when I run into problems, and I haven't really been able to find local JavaME meetups.  Does anyone know of an IRC channel for JavaME in general or MIDlet development specifically?

Comment: A similar question exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288424/irc-channel-for-iphone-developers - however, those channels are specifically iPhone-related.  I'm looking for something which is general or applies to JavaME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##j2me on freenode  there is also ##blackberry

They are generally very friends although the channel can be quiet at times since most people idle.